# Validates presense vs null false in Rails models/tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I was playing around with Rails admin and I noticed something.

Attributes which are defined as below in model, counted as "Required" in Rails admin

```
 validates :user, presence: true
```

However, attributes which are defined as below in table (schema/migration) still counted as "Optional"

```
t.datetime "created_at",:null => false
```

I would have assumed that both of these are identical except perhaps the level from which the validation error pops up. Am I wrong or is this a Rails admin error? Are both of these ensuring that this field will be required for a successful field save or is there a difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding a `:null => false` means that this is a database restriction, i.e. under no circumstance will the database allow a null value.

Adding a `presence: true` is a model level validation so will take place before the object is inserted into the database. There may be a case you want to break these validations (for example edge cases or in your specs) You can then skip validation using `:validates => false` and the object will still go into the database, with a null DB restriction, this won't happen.

Comment: Interesting, didnt know that I can opt out, so to speak, of validation. But besides that can I say that externally the behavior is the same? i.e I will not be able to save unless this property is assigned, in either case?

Comment: Yes, providing you always use the rails methods and don't pass `validates => false`

Comment: can you share a concrete example on why you would prefer to validate in the model instead of the DB ?

Answer (score 2):

```
t.datetime "created_at",:null => false
```

is telling the database not to accept null values. 
Whereas, `validates :user, presence: true` is like telling the Rails app to not accept null values.
But it would be good to have them integrated, like having :null => false to also have it registered with Rails to have a model validation.